# 64bit VM host environment for debian linux similar to VMware player on Wintel?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, 64bit

I have an Intel Core Duo i3-2100 running a flavour of Debian. I understand Virtual Box is x86-only so is there any similar open source Virtualisation environment that can host images like VMware player on a Windows platform?

Comment: Virtualbox can run on a 64bit plattform.

Comment: If you run Debian you should be able to install it directly via `apt-get install virtualbox-qt`

Comment: google 'virtualbox 64bit' and you don't even have to click the first entry to be able to read: "VirtualBox supports 64-bit guest operating systems, even on 32-bit host ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox can run in a 64-bit system. Installing the `.deb` from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) (choose whether you're using Debian 6.0 or 7.0) should work.